# how can i capture every "set -x" log to syslog?

Tags: bash, syslog

The scenario is that

I have a shell script that run a few complicated command with different parameters and options.

Those parameters and options are passed by third party applications, such that I may not know exactly what parameters and options are passed each time to the shell script

So in order to know that, i use set -x at the start of the shell script to see what exactly the command is running. And i wanna move those debugger message from set -x to the syslog using logger.

i use trap to do

```
trap "logger $(BASH_COMMAND)" DEBUG
```

However the output of the syslog does not have the exact command it is running but sth like that..

```
apple=1
orange=2
command $apple $orange
```

.............................

but i wanna the output of the log should be

```
command 1 2
```

how can i achieve?

Comment: DEBUG shows the command *before* execution and parsing.  By the way, `$apple=1` is invalid (unless you are coding in Perl).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
#!/bin/bash

apple=1
orange=2
set -x

exec 2> >(logger)
echo $apple $orange
```

We are redirecting stderr (set -x routes to stderr, file descriptor 2) to the logger program.

In my /var/log/messages I get:

```
Aug 23 08:16:07 yogi logger: + echo 1 2
```

Comment: this is a great answer! can u describe more what does  exec2> >(logger) do?

Comment: Yes, `set -x` output goes to stderr.

Comment: `exec 2> >(logger)` redirects file descriptor 2 (stderr) to the stdin of the `logger` program.  It is called *process substitution* (see `man bash`).

Comment: hey one more follow up question, what does the meaning of + sign?

Comment: The + sign is the default debug prompt, `$PS4`.  More useful might be to: `export PS4='[$LINENO] '` when debugging.  For your purposes you could set it to an empty string to remove it.

Comment: Thinking about it, setting `PS4='$0'` (the name of the script) might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks @cdarke for reminding me about PS4, I forgot about it . .it's very useful . .

You can also do something like LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so wrapping things for that subprocess tree to change a lot of things (however if the subprocess call the system functions directly and not by dynlinks, especially with the IRQ 80 which afaik is where userland things shouts requests over the bridge to the kernel (in Linux).